# How to open html containing framset using flask framework

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to open index.html,

But can not find pic.html

How could i do

pic.html and index.html are all in the templates

index.html

```
  <body>
    <iframe src="pic.html"></iframe>
  </body>
```

flaskdemo.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask doesn't serve files from its `templates` directory. You would need to set up a route for `/pic.html` and render the appropriate template as part of that:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/pic.html')
def pic():
    return render_template("pic.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```